# Visual Studio 2008 and Business Intelligence Development Studio

Tags: visual-studio, bids

I installed the SQL Server 2008 R2 and now I have the Visual Studio installed with the Business Intelligence tools (which I need).

But now I need the other Visual Studio tools, like C++, C#, etc...

Before I have to use the BIDS tools I used to install the Visual Studio 2008 Professional. (I have it free from the DreamSpark).

Can I simply install it like before or I need to do a different process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sits along side BIDS and you can install both side by side